# bootstrap-wysihtml5 knockout.validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation, wysihtml5

I am trying to set up knockout validation for a wysihtml5 control. Currently I have following code:

```
<div>
   <textarea data-bind="wysihtml5: { data: Text, options: { 'font-styles': false, 'link': false, 'image': false, 'html': true } }"></textarea>
</div>
```

and the viewModel:

```
 viewModel.Text.extend({ required: true });
 viewModel.saveValidationGroup = ko.validatedObservable({
            Text: viewModel.Text
        });
viewModel.save = function () {
            if (!viewModel.saveValidationGroup.isValid()) {
                viewModel.saveValidationGroup.errors.showAllMessages();
                return false;
            } else {
                console.log(ko.toJSON(viewModel.Text));
            }
        };
```

When you run the app, the control loads properly, and when the textarea is empty, there is still set for Text viewmodel Property:

```
<span id=\"_wysihtml5-undo\" class=\"_wysihtml5-temp\"></span><span><br><ul>    </ul>  </span>
```

Question is what is the proper way of integrating the wysihtml5 control with knockout.validation.

### Edit: Custom Binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.wysihtml5 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

        var options = {};
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

        options.events = {
            "change": function () {
                var observable;
                var content = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

                if (content.data != undefined) {
                    observable = valueAccessor().data;
                } else {
                    observable = valueAccessor();
                }

                observable(control.getValue());
            }
        };

        if (value.options) {
            ko.utils.extend(options, value.options);
            delete value.options;
        }

        // if the textarea has no id, generate one to keep wysihtml5 happy
        if ($(element).attr('id') == undefined || $(element).attr('id') == '')
            $(element).attr('id', 'id_' + Math.floor(new Date().valueOf()));

        var control = $(element).wysihtml5(options).data("wysihtml5").editor;
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        //
        var control = $(element).data("wysihtml5").editor;
        var content = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};

        if (content.data != undefined) {
            control.setValue(valueAccessor().data());
        } else {
            control.setValue(valueAccessor()());
        }
    }
};
ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable('wysihtml5');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable("wysihtml5")`

Comment: Please explain why this will fix the OP's issue.

Comment: The validation library only works on value binding out of the box

Comment: Added this code but its still doesn't work. Is there a working example out there somewhere?

Comment: We need to see your custom binding

Comment: Added Custom Binding to question.

Comment: Cant really see whats wrong there, need a fiddle with all the libs loaded. But the makeBindingHandlerValidatable is doign its job see, http://jsfiddle.net/w7TSY/2

Comment: here is the updated example with the libs loaded and updated bindings: http://jsfiddle.net/jmogera/C9afu/3/

Comment: I think makeBindingHandlerValidatable is doing its job, but the wsyihtml5 control is adding the default text which i posted in the question above. That is getting stored into the property, and validation is not able to pick it up, because technically its not an empty string!

Comment: Aha, you can solve that in two ways, either fix your custom binding so it only holds the actual data (meaning it will be empty when its empty). Or create a custom validation rule that takes into accoutn the format of the custom binding